# How to connect to Amazon Athena using Simba ODBC and Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-data-wrangler

I have python code that read data from Athena and that works fine in AWS portal , but it's not working from my local computer because of security policies (using secret key is forbidden for us). This code uses awswrangler and boto3 to read the data. Now, i can connect to Athena from my computer via pyodbc and Simba Athena and that's fine. The problem is that i don't see how can i use this connection in awswrangler as i want to use the existing implementation there. Is there a way to pass pyodbc connection to awswrangler ? Or if it's possible to read the keys from pyodbc connection and pass them to awswrangler ?